React Native (Expo Go) crashes on going back
Currently trying to do some routing in React Native using Expo Go. I am able to route to new pages via useRouter().push() but when going back to a previous page, Expo Go crashes without any error messages.
Here is the source code:
// index.tsx
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

export default function Index() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>Edit app/index.tsx to edit this screen.</Text>
      <Button title="Profile" onPress={() => router.push("profile")} />
    </View>
  );
}

// profile.tsx
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

export default function Profile() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>Edit app/index.tsx to edit this screen.</Text>
      <Button title="Profile" onPress={() => router.back()} />
    </View>
  );
}

// _layout.tsx

import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function Layout() {
  return <Stack />;
}


The source code was initially created by using npx create-expo-app projectName. I am running Expo Go on an iOS device. On the web version routing appears to work so I'm lead to assume there is something wrong with using Expo Go on an iOS device but I'm not sure.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Did you seen what is your both function name? (you have share both function with same name). and more things you have used push so when you go back to another screen having the same name of the both screen so I thing it might creating the crashing issue.

@VinayUpadhyay sorry that was just a typo, I corrected how the function name should actually look
